# Move register value into an array

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I'm working on this assembly problem where I'm looping through each element in `array1` and storing the index of that array where the entry is "F".

I'm using MASM for x86 intel processors. Assembly Language

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
array1 BYTE "FMMFMFMMFFMMFFFMFMFM",0
indexa1 BYTE SIZEOF array1 DUP(?)
ArraySize = ($ - array1)

.code
main PROC

mov esi,0          ; index
mov ecx,ArraySize

L1: cmp esi,ecx            ; check to continue loop
    jl  L2                 ; continue
    jmp L5                 ; exit

L2: cmp array1[esi], "F" ; Check if "F"
    je L3                ; jump if "F"
    jmp L4               ; jump to L4 if not "F"

L3: 
   mov indexa1[ah], esi   ; store index number,---- ERROR ----
   inc ah
   jmp L4

L4: inc esi ; increment loop counter
    jmp L1  ; jump to beginning

L5: movzx eax, ah
    call DumpRegs

exit    
main ENDP
END main
```

Why do I get an error trying to store the index in indexa1?
Error says, must be index or base register

Comment: Can you please specify which assembler you're using (MASM, TASM, NASM...) and what the error exactly says?

Comment: Sure! MASM for x86 intel processors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`indexa1[ah]` doesn't match any valid addressing mode on the x86. Use a 32-bit register (e.g. `eax`) as the counter instead.

See figure 3-11 in [Intel's Software Developer's Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html).

Comment: Damn! I was sure that this is the problem, but I didn't have time to check it and I didn't want to post it without confirming. :)

Comment: Thanks! Could I instead set up a pointer to index array,             mov edx,OFFSET indexa1 ; pointer to indexarray                                          and then in L3                                                              mov [edx],esi ; to store the index                                           inc edx;

Comment: Sure. In fact, that would probably be better (since you end up with a smaller instruction inside the loop).